# IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got -2) with torch_geometry

Tags: python, pytorch

I have some trouble with IndexError in my GCN code.
The error occurred on the GCNConv layer.
I cannot understand why self.node_dim is included in the size function, shown in the error code.

How can I solve this problem?
data.x is node_feature in which the number of features for each node is just one, and the number of nodes is 2058.

Thanks in advance.

'''

```
class GCNEncoder(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        super(GCNEncoder, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = GCNConv(in_channels, out_channels, cached=True)
        self.conv2 = GCNConv(out_channels, out_channels, cached=True)

    def forward(self, x, edge_index):
        x = self.conv1(x, edge_index).relu()
        return self.conv2(x, edge_index)

class OurGAE(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, num_features, out_chennels, node):
        super(OurGAE, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = GCNEncoder(num_features, out_channels)
        
        self.linear = nn.Linear(out_channels, len(node))
    
    def encode(self, node_feature, edge_lst):
        z = self.encoder(node_feature, edge_lst)
        return z
    
    def predict(self, z):        
        predicted_node_features = self.linear(z)
        return predicted_node_features
    
    
############ train model #######

dataset = OurDataset(one_node_feature, super_edge_lst)

out_channels = 16
num_features = dataset.num_features

model = OurGAE(num_features, out_channels, node)

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = model.to(device)

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
epochs = 100

criterion = nn.MSELoss()

#model.train()

for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):

    loss_ep = 0
    for data in dataset:    

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        x = data.x.to(device)
        edge_lst = data.edge_index.to(device)
        
        z = model.encode(x, edge_lst)
        
        super_z = z[-1]
        
        predicted_x = model.predict(super_z)
        
        loss = criterion(x.reshape(-1), predicted_x)
        
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        loss_ep += loss.cpu().detach().data.numpy()

    if epoch % 1 == 0:
        print(f"epoch: {epoch}, loss : {loss_ep}") '''

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-103-9dd243b81c8e> in <module>
     71         edge_lst = data.edge_index.to(device)
     72 
---> 73         z = model.encode(x, edge_lst)
     74 
     75         super_z = z[-1]

<ipython-input-103-9dd243b81c8e> in encode(self, node_feature, edge_lst)
     36 
     37     def encode(self, node_feature, edge_lst):
---> 38         z = self.encoder(node_feature, edge_lst)
     39         return z
     40 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

<ipython-input-103-9dd243b81c8e> in forward(self, x, edge_index)
     15 
     16     def forward(self, x, edge_index):
---> 17         x = self.conv1(x, edge_index).relu()
     18         return self.conv2(x, edge_index)
     19 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch_geometric/nn/conv/gcn_conv.py in forward(self, x, edge_index, edge_weight)
    159                 if cache is None:
    160                     edge_index, edge_weight = gcn_norm(  # yapf: disable
--> 161                         edge_index, edge_weight, x.size(self.node_dim),
    162                         self.improved, self.add_self_loops)
    163                     if self.cached:

IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got -2)
```

Comment: Did you ever find out what was causing the error?

Comment: What is the shape of `x` and `edge_lst` in the line `z = model.encode(x, edge_lst)`?

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: reshape your data-points to `[num_nodes, num_node_features]` =>`[2058, 1]` before constructing the dataset.

It looks like the `OurDataset` you created doesn't fit the assumptions of the graph dataset. I just assume this is because you have only one feature at each node, and you most probably didn't reshape the data before passing it to the Dataset.

Taken from the [documentation](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/introduction.html#data-handling-of-graphs): Data Handling of Graphs

- data.x: Node feature matrix with shape [num_nodes, num_node_features]

```
from torch_geometric.data import Data

edge_index = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 1, 2], [1, 0, 2, 1]], dtype=torch.long)

x_wrong_dims = torch.tensor([-1, 0, 1], dtype=torch.float)
data_wrong_dims = Data(x=x_wrong_dims, edge_index=edge_index)
data_wrong_dims.x.size()
# torch.Size([3])
data_wrong_dims.x.size(-2)
# IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got -2)

x_correct_dims = torch.tensor([-1, 0, 1], dtype=torch.float).reshape([-1, 1])
data_correct_dims = Data(x=x_correct_dims, edge_index=edge_index)
data_correct_dims.x.size()
# torch.Size([3, 1])
data_correct_dims.x.size(-2)
# 3
```

As to the question why `gcn_norm` uses the `x.size(self.node_dim)` I would assume that the function has to [infer along which dimension to aggregate](https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric/blob/67ed16492863378b8434b03713a75924f0cc5df1/torch_geometric/nn/conv/gcn_conv.py#L49) for the normalization and [node_dim is -2 by default](https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric/blob/67ed16492863378b8434b03713a75924f0cc5df1/torch_geometric/nn/conv/message_passing.py#L82) which means it aggregates over the second to last dimensions which in the case of the correctly shaped dataset is the `num_nodes` dimension.